# Intercept input and output of each function in an MVEL expression

Tags: java, interceptor, mvel

I am quite new to MVEL. What I am trying to achieve is to log input and outputs of every function in an expression.

For example, having the following expression

```
h.function1('value1') != h.function2('value2')
```

what I am trying to log is the input and output values of `function1` and `function2`. I read about [Interceptors](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Transwiki:MVEL_Language_Guide#Interceptors). If I do undestand right, to add and interceptor I need to rewrite the above expression as the following.

```
@Intercept h.function1('value1') != @Intercept h.function2('value2')
```

However, I cannot force my users to add the `@Intercept` annotation.

Which is the best way to accomplish this task? Have I to resume Spring AOP? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not @Intercept but the name of intercept you put in map. Bellow is @test annotation. Please check detail here https://github.com/mvel/mvel/blob/master/src/test/java/org/mvel2/tests/core/CoreConfidenceTests.java

```
interceptors.put("test",
        testInterceptor);

 executeExpression(compileExpression("@test System.out.println('MIDDLE');",
        null,
        interceptors));
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. However you confirmed me that is mandatory to put an annotation into the expression to accomplish the task using exclusively MVEL, don't you?

Comment: Yep, there are doc in source code (check doxygen for method compileExpression) http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=mvel-master/src/main/java/org/mvel2/MVEL.java